# Startup issue--Debian 8.2 installed in VirtualBox

Tags: debian, virtualbox, command

I'm a first-time Linux user, installing Linux in VirtualBox for programming of a Beaglebone Black. I have installed Debian 8.2 in VirtualBox and it boots OK, BUT I am able to get only the Activities screen. How can I get to the command screen so I can enter commands and get responses?

Answer (score 0):

I searched for "command", got a result for "terminal", clicked on it and a terminal appeared. Works OK.